# Neuroimaging in SPM & GIFT - Regressor Convolution and fitting a GLM to ICA data

Tags: matlab, generalized-linear-model, neuroscience

I have two kind of disparate questions. I am attempting to replicate the following paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811916300428

I am using SPM to perform preprocessing and first-level GLM analyses on fear conditioning data while using the GIFT toolbox to perform ICA on this data.

Experiment background: We had 3 groups that all underwent fear conditioning in an MRI where they saw 2 different shapes and got shocked.

- Group 1: **Delay** - Saw shapes for 8s. One shape always coterminated with a shock (CS+) while the other never did (CS-)
- Group 2: **Trace** - Saw shapes for 4s, then a black screen (Trace Interval; TI) for 4s, at the end of which they got shocked during one shape (CS+) but not the other (CS-).
- Group 3: **Unpaired** - Control group. Saw 2 shapes for 8s but shocks were supplied during the intertrial intervals that followed and followed each shape an equal number of times (e.g. CS1 & CS2).

As a beginner the statistics part of this is confusing me conceptually and technically. After I've done all the preprocessing I fit a GLM to the data. For all groups I'm going to have the first same 2 task-based regressors (e.g. the CS+ and CS- since I'm just going to randomly assign the Unpaired group's CS1 to CS+ and CS2 to CS- as they are counterbalanced) but the durations of the stimuli will be different, yes? (i.e. 8 for both CSs in the Delay and Unpaired groups and 4 for the CSs in the Trace group). And since I am also interested in activity during the TIs in the trace group I would have 2 FURTHER task-based regressors - 4s in duration - in the Trace participants' GLM which will NOT appear in the other groups' GLMs?

My second question here has to do with regressors of no interest. In addition to motion parameters I want to include shock as a regressor of no interest but should I do there - where the shock is NOT convolved with any basis function (i.e. the value of 1 when shock is administered and a value of 0 everywhere else) or should I include it as a convolved regressor? I'm asking because, while the shock is a discrete stimulus I would have thought there would be a fairly typical response similar to those seen to the CSs, but I'm not interested in response to shock as part of my experimental question so I don't know where to put it.

At this point I have also taken the preprocessed data and run it through ICA using the GIFT software. I have gotten out ~20 pretty good looking ICs. At this point the paper says they say the following:

> "To identify task-relatedness of ICs, a general linear model (GLM) was
>   fitted to each IC's time course. First, subject-specific regressors for each
>   combination of stimulus and context were created for each of four imaging
>   runs in SPM8 using convolution of a canonical hemodynamic response
>   function with the stimulus onsets. Then, the beta-estimates of
>   each regressor in the GLM that best predicted the back-reconstructed
>   IC time course were estimated. Finally, a 2 × 2 × 2 ANOVA on beta estimates
>   with the factors stimulus (CS+, CS−), context (acquisition,
>   extinction), and time (initial or repeated presentation) was used to
>   identify significant differences in functional connectivity between CS+
>   and CS− presentations for each context."

I think I get this up to a point. So the line that starts with, "...subject-specific regressors..." means exactly what I already did but creating the GLM and including the appropriate onsets and conditions for each subjects, yes? The next line is what I don't understand. I understand that when you run the GLM you get beta estimates for each condition (e.g. one for the CS+ and one for the CS- for everyone but then also one for each TI for the Trace group) and the beta estimates are just numbers representing how well that ONE variable timecourse (e.g. the CS+ timecourse not taking into account the other variables?) fits the data, correct? But what does it mean to estimate the regressor that best predicted the IC timecourse?

I think I get how to do the ANOVA so it's just this one line that's confusing me at this point.